# BroadcastReceiver app shows bugs

Tags: android, android-layout

I made this really small app that will just listen to any ringer mode change broadcasts, and trigger a toast to show on the screen saying "Ringer Mode Changed". I don't know where I am going wrong. The IDE is now showing any errors, so maybe there is a semantics error or such.

Here is the Receiver.java file:

```
package com.example.android.testingbroadcastreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringer Mode Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.testingbroadcastreceiver">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent_filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent_filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The MainActivity.java file does not have anything related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you're exact problem is, but if Receiver.java is its own class and not a fragment, try replacing the "Context" in your toast with "this". 
Your code should look like this:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ringer Mode Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I used 'this' instead of 'Context', but this error shows up:

Comment: error: no suitable method found for makeText(Receiver,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Receiver cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Receiver cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: I really need help with this, if someone could help with this, that would be great.